# How can i build mouseless technology with arduino?

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-mega, robotics

I want to build mouseless technology with arduino as shown in this [link](http://www.pranavmistry.com/projects/mouseless/)

Can anyone tell me how to approach this with arduino? Or what can be the logic behind it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is far far far too broad. No one is going to come here, post all the electrical schematics you need, all the code you need, and walk you through step by step. That's not how this works. The stack exchange requires that the poster make some effort to make progress in thier project before posting specific problems they are having.

That being said I will say that what you want to achieve is not possible on only an arduino. The method you posted in the video requires a lot of image processing to track the blobs. This is not something a microcontroller such as the arduino can achieve. A more powerful Intel based device may have some potential for your project but I doubt it.

I once did image processing with the raspberry pi. The pi itself is still not powerful enough to perform real time image processing to a good level, however it's a possibility that it could work (my image processing was more complicated than processing a binary image and tracking dots).

The ideal solution for you would be to do exactly what this guy has done. Build an application on a laptop or desktop computer which has enough power for the image processing. I suggest taking this route first even if downscaling to a raspberry pi is possible in the future, it will introduce you to image processing, and at least you know that it CAN work, as there is a working example.

Look up OpenCV if you havnt already, download, build it, follow tutorials and start from there! Then I think you should aim to build an application that tracks white objects in the frame. And that would be your first step to completion.

Comment: Thanks C.W.G for explanation,
I will definitely try OpenCV as you suggested.